# Struts2 not able to display output

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to display the list data using struts 2 tags. I have list has follows

List ==> Array of Object ==> Object of class

i can get the values from list using java code as follows

```
for(int i=0;i<redemptionDetails.size();i++)
        {
            Object[] Obj=(Object[])redemptionDetails.get(i);
            PointsRedemption ptredim=(PointsRedemption)Obj[0];
            System.out.println(ptredim.getCarrierId());             

        }
```

where `redemptionDetails` is list.

but when I try to display using Struts2 tags I am not able to view details

I have tried below using Struts2 tags

```
<s:iterator value="redemptionDetails" status="redemptionDetails">

                <s:set var="redemptionObject"
                    value="redemptionDetails.PointsRedemption"
                    scope="application"></s:set>

                <s:set var="productObject"
                    value="redemptionDetails.PointsProduct"
                    scope="application"></s:set>
                    <script>
                    //alert(<s:property value="#redemptionObject" />);
                    </script>
                <tr>
                    <td><s:property value="#application.redemptionObject.productCode" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="#application.productObject.productCode" /></td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
```

but I am not able to get the desire result. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display values in JSP inside `<s:iterator>` tag use `top` keyword to get current iterator value.

```
<s:iterator value="redemptionDetails">
    <s:property value="top[0].carrierId"/>
</s:iterator>
```