# Struts2: how to display an Hashmap<Integer, Object> in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, hashmap

I'm using struts2. Through my action, I get a Hashmap from a Resultset of java:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,Object>> customer = new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,Object>>();
if(!(finalQuery.equals(""))){
    ResultSet rsFinalQuery = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(finalQuery);
    ResultSetMetaData md = rsFinalQuery.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();
    while (rsFinalQuery.next()){
         HashMap<Integer,Object> row = new HashMap<Integer,Object>();
         for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; ++i){           
             row.put(i,rsFinalQuery.getObject(i));
         }
         biReport.add(row);
    }
}
```

This is my action class:

```
public class Actionclass implements SessionAware {
    private Data db;
    private Map<String, Object> session;
    ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,Object>> customer = new ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,Object>>();

    public String execute() {
        db = (Data) session.get("db");
        this.customer = (ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Object>>) 
                                   db.illustrateReport(this.reportID).get(1);

        return "success";    
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getColumnNames() {
        return columnNames;
    }

    public void setColumnNames(ArrayList<String> columnNames) {
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Object>> getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setBiReport(ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Object>> biCustomer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map arg0) {
        this.session = arg0;
    }
}
```

And this is my jsp:

```xml
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<TABLE>       
<TR>
<s:iterator value="customer">
            <option value='<s:property value="value" />'></option> 
        </s:iterator>    
        </TR>     
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my issue is how can I display the table stored in my HashMap in jsp as a table using struts? I'm not using beans or HTTPservlet and I don't want to have java code in my jsp.

Would be great if you could help!

Comment: of course struts2tags. But have you ever displayed a HashMap with an Object inside?

Comment: What exact problem do you have? Post your jsp.

Comment: You are iterating only list. What is `value`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009137/1654265

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Displaying is pretty straightforward comparing to updating.

Comment: True but I'm linking this answer everytime I see this non-OOP "structures" that creeps me out ... it's my pet-peeve :)

Comment: @Aleksandr: You are right! I'm only iterating over the Arraylist. Do know how to first iterate over the arraylist and then over the value of my hashmap? (Because key would be RowID and value the values of my table row from Resultset which is of type Object in java)

Comment: Also why there are options without a select ? And can't you use s:select tag for this ?

Comment: I'm totally new to struts2. Could you show how it should look like?

Comment: So what is this, a List<Select> ?

Comment: The `top` keyword - http://stackoverflow.com/q/20369158/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM along with the [other ways](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19516627/1654265) :)

Comment: What's the internal structure of the `Object`? Also, how are there this many people still using Struts?

Comment: This is Struts2, not Struts. It also has almost nothing to do with Struts, apart for the name.

Comment: It is also totally unclear to me **why on earth you are printing the column names for every record**. Column names don't change ! Do you want to print the column values, instead ? :|

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved it. This is the right code in the jsp file:

```xml
<tr>
    <s:iterator value="customer">
        <s:iterator value="top">
            <td><s:property value="value"/> </td>
        </s:iterator>    
    </s:iterator>
</tr>
```

Thank you everybody for your help!

Comment: Pay attention to <tr> and <s:iterator> nesting